# Calling super if and only if the parent class has the function

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript

Ordinarily in Coffeescript, if I want to call a function that exists in a parent class, I just toss a call to super at the end.  e.g.

```
initialize: (options) ->
  // do some stuff here
  super options
```

I'm working with a framework that has some functions which are called if they're defined such as `onShow` or `onClose`.  In many classes, these functions don't exist, but may get added later on in development.  Frequently, I'll be defining a class which extends another class, and call `super` in my `onShow` method out of habit:

```
onShow: ->
  // do things
  super
```

This generated Javascript of the form:

```
 return ClassName.__super__.onShow.apply(this, arguments);
```

Unfortunately, this presumes that `onShow` exists in the parent class, which it may not.  Ordinarily, I can work around a potentially existent function by doing `funcName?()` which generates the Javascript:

```
  if (typeof funcName === "function") {
    funcName();
  }
```

but `super?()` does not work as expected, generating this Javascript:

```
return typeof (_base = ClassName.__super__.onClose.apply(this, arguments)) === "function" ? _base() : void 0;
```

when I would expect, instead:

```
return typeof (_base = ClassName.__super__.onClose) === "function" ? _base.apply(this, arguments) : void 0;
```

Clearly, I can manually remove the calls to `super`, but I'd like to make my child classes to automatically inherit the parent class behavior if the parents are changed later on.

Is there a mnemonic in Coffeescript to do what I'm attempting here?

Answer (score 3):

Yay, **`super`**, which is answer is not, but let's dive in anyway...

## When we know we have `super`:

First, let's look at the standard situation, where we have a class **`Animal`**, with a `speak` function. We also have a **`Bird`** which extends **`Animal`** and has it's own `speak` function, which calls the `super` version from **`Animal`**.

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name, @sound = 'AAAARGH!') ->
  speak: -> alert "My name is #{@name}, #{@sound}"

class Bird extends Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->
    super @name, 'CA-CAW!'
  speak: ->
    alert 'I\'m a bird!'
    super
```

This of course works as expected, when it's used as followed:

```
new Bird('Harry').speak()
```

Which makes sense when we look at the generated **JavaScript**:

```
Bird = (function(_super) {
  __extends(Bird, _super);

  function Bird(name) ...

  Bird.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert('I\'m a bird!');
    return Bird.__super__.speak.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  return Bird;

})(Animal);
```

This generated **JS** also shows us that we have two ways we can access the super-class of a class from a method of that class:

- `_super`
- `Class.__super__`

Neither of these are really that great as options, but they work if you're desperate...

## When we don't know if we have `super`:

```
class MuteAnimal
  constructor: (@name, @sound = '') ->

class BeakTapedShutBird extends MuteAnimal
  constructor: (@name) ->
    super @name, 'HELP!!!'
  speak: ->
    alert '**muffled noise**'
    # could also be @__super__::speak?, pick your poison:
    if _super::speak? then super
```

The generated JS will respect our reference to `_super`, so we get the following:

```
BeakTapedShutBird = (function(_super) {
  __extends(BeakTapedShutBird, _super);

  function BeakTapedShutBird(name) ...

  BeakTapedShutBird.prototype.speak = function() {
    if (_super.prototype.speak != null) {
      return BeakTapedShutBird.__super__.speak.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
  return BeakTapedShutBird;
})(MuteAnimal);
```

This isn't great, and it's hardly idiomatic, but at least it means we don't get the **`error`** if the `super` function isn't there?

```
tapeSlippedOff = Math.random() > 0.5
if (tapeSlippedOff)
  MuteAnimal::speak = Animal::speak

new BeakTapedShutBird('Geoff').speak()
```

Answer (score -1):

Super is a reserved word, according to [CoffeeScript's documentation: Classes, Inheritance, Super](http://coffeescript.org/#classes).